# What is the difference between these two ways to read lines in Python with `sys.stdin`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, sys

I don't think I understand the ways to read lines from the input using `sys.stdin` .

What is the difference between

```
import sys
while True:
    foo(sys.stdin.readline())
```

and

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    foo(line)
```

and why would I pick one choice over the other?

Also, how would I get the behavior of

```
import sys
first_line = sys.readline()
foo(first_line)
while True:
    bar(sys.readline())
```

by using a for-in loop? Specifically, what would be an elegant way to treat the first line separately from the other lines in the input? Does somethine along the lines of `for line in  sys.stdin` still work?

Comment: there is no technical difference

Comment: They will behave differently when `stdin` is closed.

Comment: @hop: What do you mean by "no technical difference" exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) here; it's just a normal text file object.

Iterating any iterable, including a file object, with `for x in iterable:`, just calls `next` on it over and over until it raises a `StopIteration`.

Notice that this means that if you want to skip over a header line before processing the rest of a file, you can just call `next(f)` before the loop.

And [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline) does the same thing as `next`, except for the `hint` parameter (which you're not using), and what happens on various error conditions (which aren't likely to matter here), and what happens at EOF: `readline` returns an empty string, `next` raises a `StopIteration`.

So, there's no *general* reason to pick one over the other in general; it comes down to which is more readable in your particular case.

---

If your goal is to loop over all the lines, it's a lot more readable to use a `for` loop. Compare:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    do_stuff(line)

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    do_stuff(line)
```

---

If, on the other hand, your loop involves reading variable chunks of stuff with some non-trivial logic, `readline` is usually going to be clearer:

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    while line.rstrip().endswith('\\'):
        line = line.rstrip().rstrip('\\') + sys.stdin.readline()
    do_stuff(line)

logical_line = ''
try:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if logical_line:
            logical_line += line
        if not line.rstrip().endswith('\\'):
            do_stuff(logical_line)
            logical_line = ''
except StopIteration:
    if logical_line:
        do_stuff(logical_line)
```

Comment: One thing I'll point out is that stepping through one can get a solid understanding of what the differences are. For example with `pdb` the for loop would take twice as many steps as the while loop (eg. "hello" + 3 times).

Comment: @l'L'l Good point. Stepping through a small program is a great way to learn how _any_ part of Python works, so ideally, everyone should learn how to do it early on…

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    foo(sys.stdin.readline())
```

This code will loop forever. If there is an EOF on `sys.stdin` -- for instance, if input was redirected from a file, and the end of that file has been reached -- then it will call `foo('')` repeatedly. This is probably bad.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    foo(line)
```

This code will stop looping when an EOF is encountered. This is good.

If you want to handle the first line differently, you can simply call `sys.stdin.readline()` once before entering the loop:

```
first_line = sys.readline()
foo(first_line)
for line in sys.stdin:
    bar(line)
```